# Ruby: rescue an OAuthException exception

Tags: ruby, exception

I'm occasionally getting an OAuthException and am trying to catch it with:

```
rescue OAuthException => exception
# exception handling code here
```

However I get:

```
rescue in <main>': uninitialized constant OAuthException (NameError)
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

==== UPDATE

Here's how I've solved it currently. The fact I'm having to do a message.match() seems a bit hacky.

```
rescue GemModule::GemSubmodule::APIError => exception
    if exception.message.match("OAuthException")
```

Any improvements?

Comment: I don't get a log entry. It just exits giving the line number of the `begin` statement and the `rescue in <main>` message above.

Comment: Yes, there's a parent class delivering this exception.

Comment: If an APIError is raised, do you need to do specific things depending on the error message ?

Answer (score 0):

```
begin
  raise OAuthException, 'hello'
rescue OAuthException => e
  puts e
end

--output:--
1.rb:3:in `rescue in <main>': uninitialized constant OAuthException (NameError)
    from 1.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

.

```
class OAuthException < Exception
end

begin
  raise OAuthException, 'hello'
rescue OAuthException => e
  puts e
end

--output:--
hello
```

The error message is telling you that there is no such thing as an OAuthException in ruby.

Comment: Yes, not in Ruby. The exception is delivered by a class from a Ruby gem.

Comment: Then require the gem in your file.